# Storage Spaces Direct CSV vs non-CSV volume performance difference

Tags: storage-spaces-direct

In a Win2019 S2D deployment having 4 nodes of 4 SSD per node, I create a new NTFS volume and I create a new CSV_NTFS volume.  I'm using diskspd to test.  I'm running the tests from the node in which I will obtain DirectIO.

I'm getting 250k/610k write/read 4k IOPs on the NTFS and 187k/954k IOPs on the CSV.  I would think the underlying subsystem is essentially identical, except that the NTFS volume is shared in the case of CSV.

Why would **read performance** be markedly **better** when the volume is **using CSVFS** or is this an anomaly?

Answer (score 4):

Bringing in distributed lock / arbitration layer (CSVFS) on top of the NTFS/ReFS comes with a performance penalty.

TL;DR: Everything works as expected.

Comment: I guess my post is confusing.  I'm asking why there is a read performance gain while using CSVFS.  How would CSVFS cause a gain in read performance over its non-use?

Comment: CSV Cache and partner nodes participating in read I/O (data is getting delivered from the multiple nodes @ the same time). Turn CSV Cache OFF and put down all the partner nodes to re-run the test and see would it make any difference.

Comment: Ok, you are right.  While diskspd is often run with "cache disabled", the term "cache" here does not include CSV cache (I assumed it had).  I needed to turned off CSV cache (BlockCacheSize=0) to perform a meaningful comparison.  Thanks.

Comment: It’s not only that. SMB Multichannel and reading replicas from the other nodes should be disabled as well.

Comment: Why should SMB Multichannel be disabled too?  According to the documentation you aren't going to get the use of RDMA (which I use in my network) unless you have this enabled.

Comment: Because you’ll read the data from the partner nodes rendering whole set of your test runs basically useless.